# unexpected T_STRING on Linux

Tags: php, linux, zend-framework, doctrine

I've just uploaded my Zend project to my CentOS server. I am using Doctrine ORM, and so this requires me to state the namespaces I am using.

My project runs fine on my windows machine, but when I try and run it on the server, I get the

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING or '(' in ************/Bootstrap.php on line 2
```

error. Line 2 is

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager,
Doctrine\ORM\Configuration;
```

I'm fairly new to Linux, and maybe I'm wrong in assuming it's Linux that is at fault, so how can I resolve this error?

Thanks

Comment: Has nothing to do with the fact that the OS is Linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update PHP. Namespaces are supported with PHP >= 5.3 and you probably have a version below this installed on your server.

Comment: Thanks for your speedy reply. I thought I had installed the most recent version of PHP but evidently not.